# Can't access my webpage on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am learning codeigniter but has gone to some trouble. I created a folder in my htdocs and named it as ci_beginning then I created a controller called hello2 in the controller folder and you_view2 in the view folder.
Code for my controller:

```
    if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Hello2 extends CI_Controller{

    // declare variables or class properties
    var $name;
    $var $color:

    function __contruct(){
        parent::__construct();

        // give default value
        $this->name = "Hello";
        $this->color = "red";
    }

    function you(){
        $data['name']=$this->name;
        $data['color']=$this->color;

        // define variable sent to views
        $this->load->view('you_view2', $data);
    }
}
```

code for my view:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Beginning Codeigniter</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="color:<?php echo $color ?>">Hello <?php echo $name; ?></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I try to access it by using this in my browser:

```
http://localhost/ci_beginning/index.php/hello2/you
```

It's giving me a 404 page not found error. Please tell me what I am doing wrong. If you can show me how to make this easier I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Try to use access modifiers for your class properties and methods. More on the subject you can find here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php. It is considered a good practice, improves readability of your code and follows [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Codeigniter 3 then make sure that your file name should start with capital letter and make sure the file name is same as your controller name and in this case it must be `Hello2.php` in your `controllers` folder.

Also there is error in line,

```
$var $color:
```

It should be

```
var $color;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out but I still can't access the you_view2 page.

Comment: Is `http://localhost/ci_beginning/index.php working`? and have you any `htaccess` in ci_beginning folder

Comment: If you are using Codeigniter 3 then make sure that your file name should start with capital letter like `Hello2.php`

Comment: Oh. I have the .htaccess. It is in the controller folder.

Comment: In `ci_beginning folder`. And if `http://localhost/ci_beginning/index.php` is working then there is some other problem. Check that the page name is like `Hello2.php` in `controllers` folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120780/discussion-between-rohan-kumar-and-ibanez1408).

Comment: Thanks. The filename must match with the class name.

Comment: Yes it must be same